# In $\triangle ABC$, $D$ is on $AC$ such that $AB=CD$, $E$ and $F$ are midpoints of $AD$ and $BC$, and $BA$ intersects $EF$ at $M$. Prove $AM=AE$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles

> A triangle $\triangle ABC$ has a point $D$ on $AC$ such that $AB=CD$, and $E$ and $F$ are midpoints of $AD$ and $BC$, respectively. $BA$ intersects $EF$ at $M$. Prove that $AM=AE$.

[image]

I know the question utilizes the concept of the Basic Proportionality Theorem in some way, as it was given as a problem for its practice. I have tried producing parallel lines from different points to other lines in order to apply Basic Proportionality Theorem in some way, angle chasing, joining points, constructing equal lines, but it does not seem to work at all. I'm pretty sure it requires a magical construction which I am unable to see.

Any hints/ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I disagree, I don't think bioprocessing technology is relevant here at all.

Comment: wdym?This is meant to utilise school level mathematics incase biprocessing level is a thing in higher math..

Comment: https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/BPT (I was just taking a guess. It looks like someone has edited in the meaning for you now.)

Comment: That was me....

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$\triangle BIF\simeq \triangle CJF \Rightarrow BI=CJ$$

$$\triangle AGE\simeq \triangle DHE \Rightarrow IL=AG=DH=JK, AE=DE$$

$$BI=CJ, IL=JK \Rightarrow BL=CK$$

$$BL=CK, AB=CD \Rightarrow \triangle ABL\simeq \triangle DCK\Rightarrow \angle ABL=\angle DCK$$

$$\angle ABL=\angle DCK, BI=CJ \Rightarrow \triangle MBI\simeq \triangle ECJ\Rightarrow MB=EC$$

$$MB=EC, AB=CD \Rightarrow AM=DE \Rightarrow AM=AE$$

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is the midpoint of $AC$, by midpoint theorem, $FG = \dfrac{AB}{2}$ and is parallel to $AB$. That leads to $~\triangle AEM \sim \triangle GEF$

Also note that $GE = \dfrac{AB}{2} = FG$. As $\triangle GEF$ is isosceles, so must $\triangle AEM$.

$ \therefore AE = AM$

Comment: Sorry if it's obvious but why is GE=AB/2?

Comment: $GE = AG - AE, AG = AC/2, AE = AD/2$ and $AC-AD = CD = AB$

Comment: Thank you!I never imagined I was so close to the answer